# Electromagnetic $L^{2}$ potentials

Tags: resource-recommendations, classical-electrodynamics

I'm a mathematician and I work in the theory of harmonic functions. These are solutions of Laplace equation $\Delta u=0$. I saw recently that in Electrodynamics potentials behave like a solution of this equation. Is there any theory that say something about $L^{2}$ behavior of these potentials? If you have a domain where you are looking a potential(electromagnetic), can we say that $$\int_{\Omega}\vert u\left(x\right)\vert^{2}dx<\infty ?$$
Here $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ where we are looking our potential. Are there any physical papers on this topic?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) The potential in a charge free region behaves like this - if there are charges, we need to solve a Poisson equation. For the less mathematical of us physicists, can you explain your $L^2$ behaviour a bit more explicit? You want to know whether this holds for any open $\Omega$ in the charge free region?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly I'd like to know. Is it true that for every charge free region $\Omega$ potential is like that. So square a function and then integrate it over that region. Is that has to be finite?

Comment: If you allow $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^3$, it does not hold - in vacuum, every constant function is a physically correct potential (due to gauge invariance, in the end) and integrating a constant over the whole space is divergent. You might either want to require that $u(\partial \mathbb{R}^3)=0$ as boundary condition or require $\Omega$ to have a finite measure itself. Then I'm not sure, but I'll keep thinking about it. I unfortunately don't know any literature on the subject :(